# Bluefish Editor

Tags: text-editors, bluefish

I am using the "BlueFish" editor for HTML and XML editing. How do I create an XML file in the "Bluefish" editor?

Comment: I push the buttons on my keyboard. Or is this a trick question?

Comment: Just a random guess... `File > New...`